# Cannot find module '..\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'

Tags: node.js, api, npm, endpoints, yo

when i am trying to add endpoints using command "yo angular-fullstack:endpoint name", i am getting this error:

```
 module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:...npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3
```

while running command npm-install, i am getting this error

```
> error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2'
```

Comment: you mean `npm install` ?  have you try `npm install -g yo` ?

Comment: @SteevePitis i am getting this now,

`npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm a
nd is now out of date with respect to npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! path C:\Users\......\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by changing the node version to a newer version